# Unable to update ChromeDriver since Chrome for Testing released

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-for-testing

I'm using Selenium and ChromeDriver to automate the scraping of data from various websites on a Mac (arm-64). Whenever Chrome updates to a new major version, I have had to download and install the newest version of ChromeDriver to go with it. Starting after Chrome 115, the JSON endpoints no longer yield a file containing ChromeDriver. Instead, they yield a zip file containing an app called "Google Chrome for Testing". I have not been figure out how to make this work in place of the old ChromeDriver. If I install the app and try to run it, I get a message that the app is damaged. If I also just try to run my program, I still get the message about ChromeDriver not supporting that version of Chrome (CD version = 115 and Chrome version = 117).

Answer (score 2):

> If I install the app and try to run it, I get a message that the app is damaged.

## macOS says the `*.app` is damaged. What now?

See https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing?tab=readme-ov-file#macos-says-the-app-is-damaged-what-now. TL;DR:

On macOS, if you download a Chrome for Testing ZIP file *using a browser* instead of via [`@puppeteer/browsers`](https://pptr.dev/browsers-api/), `curl`, or `wget`, you might get this warning:

> “Google Chrome for Testing.app” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

This happens because macOS [Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/gatekeeper-and-runtime-protection-sec5599b66df/web) sets an extended attribute that marks the ZIP file and any files within it as “downloaded via a browser” and thus potentially dangerous.

To fix the problem, recursively remove the extended attribute:

```bash
xattr -cr 'Google Chrome for Testing.app'
```

## Chromedriver

It should be possible to download standalone chromedriver, without `cft`.

See the download URLs here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

For example: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip